# Убрать директории из пути

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение для того что бы убрать директории из пути:

```
file://localhost/D:/X/Y/1.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/A/B/2.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/Q/W/E/3.txt
```

В результате нужно получить:

```
file://localhost/D:/X/1.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/2.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для питона не знаю, как точнее должна быть регулярка, но на php вот так:

```
$first = "file://localhost/D:/X/Y/1.txt";
$first = "file://localhost/D:/X/A/B/2.txt";
$first = "file://localhost/D:/X/Q/W/E/3.txt";

/* В результате нужно получить:

file://localhost/D:/X/1.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/2.txt
file://localhost/D:/X/3.txt
 */

echo preg_replace("/(file:\/\/localhost\/D:)\/(.*?)\/(?:.*)\/(.*)/i", "($1/$2/$3)", $first);
```

Comment: А как работает ($1/$2/$3)?

Comment: <pre><code>"/(file:\/\/localhost\/D:)\/(.*?)\/(?:.*)\/(.*)/i"</code></pre>
(x) Находит x и запоминает. Это называется "запоминающие скобки".
(?:x) Находит x, но не запоминает найденное. 

Вот у нас и выходит, что $1 это первая скобка, $2 это вторая скобка, $3 - это четвертая скобка. А третью скобку мы пропускаем, т.к. "сказали", что она нам не нужна.

Comment: Все работает 

А если нужно заменить в XML:
<path>file://localhost/D:/X/Y/Z/1.txt</path>

Получается так
<path>file://localhost/D:/X/path>

Comment: echo preg_replace("/(file:\/\/localhost\/D:)\/(.*?)\/(?:.*)\/(.*?)(<\/)/i", "$1/$2/$3$4", $first);

Comment: я уже сделал так x = re.sub(pattern, r"<path>\g<1>/\g<2>/\g<3></path>", f.read())

Вроде получилось то что нужно)

Comment: @Аlexo ну и славно!)